# PHP Session Vairables for Checkout/basket system

Tags: php, html, css

Im attempting to build an E-commerce website, I'm trying to use sessions to store a product name, price and quantity in a session variable from my product details page to then be used in my basket/checkout page once the user clicks add to basket.

I have some `$_SESSION[]` but I get the error :
`Notice: Undefined index: prod_Name in C:\MAMP\htdocs\product1_details.php on line 25`
`Notice: Undefined index: prod_Price in C:\MAMP\htdocs\product1_details.php on line 26`

I don't know how to add the product name, price and quantity to a session variable so that I can display it in my basket on another page.
you wont see a session.start() as it is in my application_top.php (I was asked to do it this way)

This is my product details page -

```
<?php
require('includes/application_top.php');
$page_title='Details';
require('includes/site_header.php');
$_GET['prod_ID'];
$product_id = isset($_REQUEST['prod_ID']) ? (int) $_REQUEST['prod_ID'] : 0;
$pound ="&pound;";
?>
<style>
<?php
require('css/prod_details.css');
?>
</style>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php $product = get_product_details1($freshKickz_conn); ?>

         <?php foreach($product as $productdetails) {
 ?>



<main class="container">

  <!-- Left Column / Headphones Image -->
  <div class="left-column">
    <img data-image="red" class="active" src="<?= htmlspecialchars($productdetails['images']) ?>" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;" alt="">
  </div>
  <!-- Right Column -->
  <div class="right-column">
 
    <!-- Product Description -->
    <div class="product-description">
      <h1><?= htmlspecialchars($productdetails['prod_Name']) ?></h1>
      <p><?= htmlspecialchars($productdetails['prod_Details']) ?></p>
    </div>

    <!-- Product Pricing -->
    <div class="product-price">
      <span><?=$pound?><?= htmlspecialchars($productdetails['prod_Price'])?></span>
      <a href="basket_page.php?quantity=1&name=<?=$productdetails['prod_Name']?>" class="cart-btn">Add to Basket</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="quantity">
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <br>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="9" step="1" value="1">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<?php
} ?>
<script src="js/prodJS.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.color-choose input').on('click', function () {
        var headphonesColor = $(this).attr('data-image');

        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.left-column img[data-image = ' + headphonesColor + ']').addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

});
</script>
<?php
require('includes/application_bottom.php');
require('includes/site_footer.php');
?>
```

And this is my basket page -

```
<?php
require('includes/application_top.php');
$page_title='Your Basket';
require('includes/site_header.php');
$_SESSION['p_Name'] = $_POST['prod_Name'];
$_SESSION['p_Price'] = $_POST['prod_Price'];
?>
<style>
<?php
require('css/basket.css');
?>
</style>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-75">
    <div class="container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
            <h3>Billing Address</h3>
            <label for="fname"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="John M. Doe">
            <label for="email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john@example.com">
            <label for="adr"><i class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i> Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="adr" name="address" placeholder="542 W. 15th Street">
            <label for="city"><i class="fa fa-institution"></i> City</label>
            <input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="New York">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-50">
                <label for="state">County</label>
                <input type="text" id="county" name="county" placeholder="Cheshire">
              </div>
              <div class="col-50">
                <label for="zip">PostCode</label>
                <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" placeholder="SK11 6TF">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-50">
            <h3>Payment</h3>
            <label for="fname">Accepted Cards</label>
            <div class="icon-container">
              <i class="fa fa-cc-visa" style="color:navy;"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-cc-amex" style="color:blue;"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard" style="color:red;"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-cc-discover" style="color:orange;"></i>
            </div>
            <label for="cname">Name on Card</label>
            <input type="text" id="cname" name="cardname" placeholder="John More Doe">
            <label for="ccnum">Credit card number</label>
            <input type="text" id="ccnum" name="cardnumber" placeholder="1111-2222-3333-4444">
            <label for="expmonth">Exp Month</label>
            <input type="text" id="expmonth" name="expmonth" placeholder="September">

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-50">
                <label for="expyear">Exp Year</label>
                <input type="text" id="expyear" name="expyear" placeholder="2018">
              </div>
              <div class="col-50">
                <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
                <input type="text" id="cvv" name="cvv" placeholder="352">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="sameadr"> Shipping address same as billing
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Continue to checkout" class="btn">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-25">
    <div class="container">
      <h4>Cart
        <span class="price" style="color:black">
          <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
          <b>4</b>
        </span>
      </h4>
      <p><a href="#"><?= $_SESSION['p_Name']?></a> <span class="price">$15</span></p>
      <p><a href="#">Product 2</a> <span class="price">$5</span></p>
      <p><a href="#">Product 3</a> <span class="price">$8</span></p>
      <p><a href="#">Product 4</a> <span class="price">$2</span></p>
      <hr>
      <p>Total <span class="price" style="color:black"><b>$30</b></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
require('includes/application_bottom.php');
require('includes/site_footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: _“Im attempting to build an E-commerce website”_ - your previous questions give a strong impression, that you might be in way over your head with this. You should probably start with something smaller. (Otherwise, I can already see you come running here with one such question after the other over the next days and perhaps weeks - and teaching people basics, is really not what SO is for.)

Comment: @CBroe judging people for attempting ambitious projects also isn't what SO is for.

Comment: @Ortund to me, there is a difference between being ambitious, and _abusing_ a site like this to get absolute basics taught. And this here absolutely falls into the later category to me, when people can not even fix `Notice: Undefined index: …` problems on their own. That has been asked about countless times already, and we have extensive answers that explain almost anything one could need to know in that regard.

Comment: @CBroe I wouldnt say in over my head just stuck on a few issues hence why I came to SO, I thought that's what is was for

Comment: @CBroe I get you but there's a proper process then to be followed. Rather than berating the user who's just trying to figure stuff out and maybe doesn't know of other options, recommend a subreddit where they can ask instead and then flag the question to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error in $_POST. You are not submitting any form with method POST.

Comment: Thats because there isnt a form? should I not be using $_POST